# How do I patch apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, patch-management

Ok, so I am using apache 2.2.17 on an Ubuntu (Natty Narwhal) box.

I need to apply a patch (mod_proxy_connect-2.2.16.patch) which I downloaded from https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=26225&action=edit

however I have never done this before. I have no clue as to how to do it. It seems that I needed to recompile apache, but I cant even find the right packages (apt-get install apache2-src doesnt find anything).

Can anyone help me/ guide me in doing it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the source package and build dependencies:

```
apt-get source apache2
apt-get build-dep apache2
```

Apply the patch to the source:

```
cd apache2-2.2.17/
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

Build the debian package:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b
```

List the currently installed apache2 packages:

```
dpkg -l | egrep '^i+ +apache2'
```

Install the appropriate newly built packages (all the packages listed in the previous step) and restart apache:

```
cd ..
dpkg -i apache2_2.2.17******.deb
.......

apache2ctl restart
```

Source: http://base6.com/2009/06/07/patching-apache-on-debian/

-$

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, you've installed Apache using `apt-get` - this downloads and installs pre-built binary packages, which are customized to do things in the Debian way - file locations, default config files, upstart scripts, and niceties like logwatch are handled for you.

Compiling the software from source in Ubuntu is definitely doable, but you're then on your own as far as applying future patches and version upgrades - which will also need to have the connect-method-over-SSL patch applied, then re-compiled from source (no more `apt-get upgrade`).   And you'll need to stick to the current version of Apache instead of the one your OS came with, as Ubuntu backports security fixes from new versions).

Also, you'll need to have the understanding that anything on the internet related to an Apache install on Ubuntu is probably no longer applicable to your install of Apache - file paths, config files, compile options will all be different.

If you're set on this approach, run `apt-get install build-essential` then follow Apache's guide [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html).  It may not be worth the headache - have you considered just putting up something like stunnel to handle the SSL part to allow for the connection to hit Apache on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be:

1. install apxs2:

`apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev` (or worker if you are using it)

2. just get the source:

   apt-get source apache2
   cd apache2-2.2.17/
3. apply your patch file
4. go to directory where c file is and run `apxs2 -cia mod_proxy_connect.c`